# Book has no extract_formulas attribute calling xlrd.open_workbook()

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import xlrd

path = "C:\\Users\\m.macapanas\\Desktop\\OFCCP_Default_Values.xlsm"
excel_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
excel_worksheet = excel_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)


#Read from Excel Worksheet
print("Your Worksheet has " + str(excel_worksheet.ncols) + " columns")
print("Your Worksheet has " + str(excel_worksheet.nrows) + " rows")

for row in range (excel_worksheet.nrows):
    for col in range(excel_worksheet.ncols):
        print(excel_worksheet.cell_value(row, col), end='')
        print('\t', end='')
    print()
```

Then the result is error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/m.macapanas/IdeaProjects/OFCCP Tool/Read Excel File with Python/Pandas.py", line 4, in 
> excel_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
> File "C:\Users\m.macapanas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlrd_*init*_.py", line 141, in open_workbook
> ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
> File "C:\Users\m.macapanas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 808, in open_workbook_2007_xml
> x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
> File "C:\Users\m.macapanas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 265, in process_stream
> meth(self, elem)
> File "C:\Users\m.macapanas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 392, in do_sheet
> sheet = Sheet(bk, position=None, name=name, number=sheetx)
> File "C:\Users\m.macapanas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 326, in **init**
> self.extract_formulas = book.extract_formulas
> AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'` thats your issue. Dont know how to solve but a quick google seems to suggest it might be down to the version you are using?

Comment: I've installed Python 3.6.0

Comment: @AthenaBrielleMabuyo I think it might be the version of `xlrd` that's the problem.

Comment: I have this xlrd version. 
xlrd in c:\users\m.macapanas\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (2.0.1)

What version should I install? Do I need to uninstall my python 3.6.0 version and install the latest one? so that the xlrd packages also upgraded?

Comment: Comment suggested to check your _xlrd_ version. You did, please [edit] your question to update this info, instead of in comment.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [*xlrd* documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) states in a *warning*:

> This library will no longer read anything other than .xls files.

Your error is popping up when you attempt to open a workbook for the file `"C:\\Users\\m.macapanas\\Desktop\\OFCCP_Default_Values.xlsm"`, which has a `.xlsm` extension.

The [*xlrd* library](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) explicitly doesn't support reading the newer file formats like `.xlsm`. So you'll either have to switch libraries or find a way to downgrade your input file to supported `.xls` format.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

#### Analyze the error

> line 4, in excel_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

Your script fails to open the workbook.

> AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'

The attribute-error states, it does not find `extract_formulas` as attribute of [xlrd's `Book` object](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.book.Book).

#### Caused by unsupported file-format `.xlsx`

As [Nathaniel Ford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68656125/5730279) explained:

- *xlrd* (as of current version 2.0.1) only supports older Excel file-format `.xls`

#### See also

- [Pandas cannot open an Excel (.xlsx) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-an-excel-xlsx-file)
- [Why is python xlrd errors when opening a .xlsm instead of .xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109911/why-is-python-xlrd-errors-when-opening-a-xlsm-instead-of-xls)

### Alternative solution

Research on Stackoverflow gave:
[How can I open an Excel file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239207/how-can-i-open-an-excel-file-in-python)

[Working with Excel Files in Python](https://www.python-excel.org/) is a great resources-collection which lists popular libraries.

#### Ported to OpenPyXL

There on top: [*openpyxl*](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

> The recommended package for reading and writing **Excel 2010 files (ie: .xlsx)**

After installing using:

```sh
pip install openpyxl
```

Your code might be ported to this library like:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "C:\\Users\\m.macapanas\\Desktop\\OFCCP_Default_Values.xlsm"

excel_workbook = load_workbook(filename = path)
excel_worksheet = excel_workbook. worksheets[0] # first worksheet


# Read from Excel Worksheet
print("Your Worksheet has " + str(excel_worksheet.ncols) + " columns")
print("Your Worksheet has " + str(excel_worksheet.nrows) + " rows")

for row in excel_worksheet.rows:
    for col in excel_worksheet.cols:
        print(excel_worksheet.cell(row, col), end='')
        print('\t', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: `.xlsm` is a _Macro-Enabled Workbook for Microsoft Excel 2007_.